# Wget, downloading outdated files

Tags: wget

I am over writing a particular file (called "demo") on my server and wget-ting it. However, sometimes wget retrieves an outdated file, despite my checking on the net that the file has been updated. I've tried deleting before re-writing, sometimes I even delete all the files; but when I try to wget "demo" I still get an outdated copy.

I'm running debian on a simulated MIPS malta board (basically, linux running on MIPS) if that makes a difference.

Is this a known bug and if so, is there a way around it?

Comment: Probably nothing to do with wget, Linux or MIPS, but with a caching proxy somewhere on your connection path that's not behaving quite properly.

Comment: `wget` will always download the file again unless you specify certain parameters like `-N`. It cannot magically retrieve a previous version.

Comment: Righ,t, thank's guys.
@Mat, could you point me in the direction of some material I could read up on the issue? A quick google return hits that were a little above me.

Comment: as others have said it sounds a lot like you're hitting a proxy.  There may be some header you can add to your wget invocation that will request the cache to re-check the server.